# iterate over select columns and check if a specfic value is in these select columns and use that column name that has that value to create a new table

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

If I have below table

```
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    a|     b|    id|m2000|m2001|m2002|m2003|m2004|m2005
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|a    |world|      1|    0|    0|    1|    0|    0|    1|   
+-----+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

How do I create a new dataframe like below that checks cols m2000 to m2014 and sees if any these fields are 1. It then creates the below table where 10/10 is static. 2002 and 2005 is used as it is only 2 columns between m2000 and m2014 where 1 is in above table.

```
|id | year      | yearend   |
|1  | 10/10/2002| 12/12/2005|
|1  | 10/10/2002| 12/12/2005|
```

code to create first dataframe

```
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

data2 = [("a", "world", "1", 0, 0, 1,0,0,1),
         ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("a", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("b", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("m2000", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2001", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2002", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2003", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2004", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2005", IntegerType(), True), \
    ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame/Series constructor to make your input reproducible?

Comment: added code to create dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a dataframe with a more complete scenario, where there are rows without years to '1' and rows with more '1's:

```py
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

data2 = [("a", "world", "1", 0, 0, 1,0,0,1),
         ("b", "world", "2", 0, 1, 0,1,0,1),
         ("c", "world", "3", 0, 0, 0,0,0,0)
         ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("a", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("b", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("m2000", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2001", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2002", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2003", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2004", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("m2005", IntegerType(), True), \
    ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

|  | a | b | id | m2000 | m2001 | m2002 | m2003 | m2004 | m2005 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | world | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | b | world | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | c | world | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

For convenience, I pass your dataframe to pandas, but I will use simple iterative structures that you can integrate into spark.

```py
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
```

We retrieve the list of years excluding the first 3 columns:

```py
years = list(pandas_df.columns)[3:]
```

Finally, the code needed to generate the required dataframe is as follows (inline comments):

```py
tmp_df_data_list = []

# iterate over rows of df
for _, row in pandas_df.iterrows():
    flagged_years=[]
    
    # for each year check if col value is 1
    for y in years:
        if row[y]:  # if is 1, append col name
            flagged_years.append(y)
            
    if len(flagged_years) >= 2:
        # get first occurence as 'year' and last as 'yearend' by removing the first letter
        min_year = flagged_years[0][1:]
        max_year = flagged_years[-1][1:]

        tmp_df_data_list.append([row.id, '10/10/'+min_year, '12/12/'+max_year])

res_df = pd.DataFrame(tmp_df_data_list, columns=['id', 'year', 'yearend'])
```

Output will be:

|  | id | year | yearend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 10/10/2002 | 12/12/2005 |
| 1 | 2 | 10/10/2001 | 12/12/2005 |

Answer (score 0):

we can use pyspark native functions to create an array of the column names that have the value `1`. the array can then be used to get the `min` and `max` of years and `concat` with `"10/10/"`.

here's an example

```py
data_ls = [
    ("a", "world", "1", 0, 0, 1,0,0,1),
    ("b", "world", "2", 0, 1, 0,1,0,1),
    ("c", "world", "3", 0, 0, 0,0,0,0)
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['a', 'b', 'id', 'm2000', 'm2001', 'm2002', 'm2003', 'm2004', 'm2005'])

# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# |  a|    b| id|m2000|m2001|m2002|m2003|m2004|m2005|
# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# |  a|world|  1|    0|    0|    1|    0|    0|    1|
# |  b|world|  2|    0|    1|    0|    1|    0|    1|
# |  c|world|  3|    0|    0|    0|    0|    0|    0|
# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

yearcols = [k for k in data_sdf.columns if k.startswith('m20')]

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('yearcol_structs', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(int(c[-4:])).alias('year'), func.col(c).alias('value')) 
                            for c in yearcols]
                          )
               ). \
    withColumn('yearcol_1s', 
               func.expr('transform(filter(yearcol_structs, x -> x.value = 1), f -> f.year)')
               ). \
    filter(func.size('yearcol_1s') >= 1). \
    withColumn('year_start', func.concat(func.lit('10/10/'), func.array_min('yearcol_1s'))). \
    withColumn('year_end', func.concat(func.lit('10/10/'), func.array_max('yearcol_1s'))). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+----------+----------+
# |a  |b    |id |m2000|m2001|m2002|m2003|m2004|m2005|yearcol_structs                                                   |yearcol_1s        |year_start|year_end  |
# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+----------+----------+
# |a  |world|1  |0    |0    |1    |0    |0    |1    |[{2000, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2002, 1}, {2003, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2005, 1}]|[2002, 2005]      |10/10/2002|10/10/2005|
# |b  |world|2  |0    |1    |0    |1    |0    |1    |[{2000, 0}, {2001, 1}, {2002, 0}, {2003, 1}, {2004, 0}, {2005, 1}]|[2001, 2003, 2005]|10/10/2001|10/10/2005|
# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988511/create-a-date-range-if-a-column-value-matches-one 

could this be applied to this scenario