# create a date range if a column value matches one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using an answer found at [iterate over select columns and check if a specfic value is in these select columns and use that column name that has that value to create a new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376972/iterate-over-select-columns-and-check-if-a-specfic-value-is-in-these-select-colu/74384246#74384246)

we can use pyspark native functions to create an array of the column names that have the value `1`. the array can then be used to get the `min` and `max` of years but I want to create a new row if 1 comes after a 0.

here's an example input table

```
# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# |  a|    b| id|m2000|m2001|m2002|m2003|m2004|m2005|
# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
# |  a|world|  1|    0|    1|    1|    0|    0|    1|
# |  b|world|  2|    0|    1|    1|    1|    1|    1|
# |  c|world|  3|    1|    1|    0|    0|    1|    1|
# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want the final table to be like:

```
# +---+-----+---+--------+--------+
# |  a|    b| id|startdate|enddate|
# +---+-----+---+--------+---------
# |  a|world|  1|    2001|    2002| 
# |  a|world|  1|    2005|    2005|  
# |  b|world|  2|    2001|    2005|    
# |  c|world|  3|    2000|    2001|    
# |  c|world|  3|    2004|    2005|
# +---+-----+---+-----+-----+-----+

python
data_ls = [
    ("a", "world", "1", 0, 0, 1,0,0,1),
    ("b", "world", "2", 0, 1, 0,1,0,1),
    ("c", "world", "3", 0, 0, 0,0,0,0)
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['a', 'b', 'id', 'm2000', 'm2001', 'm2002', 'm2003', 'm2004', 'm2005'])


yearcols = [k for k in data_sdf.columns if k.startswith('m20')]

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('yearcol_structs', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(int(c[-4:])).alias('year'), func.col(c).alias('value')) 
                            for c in yearcols]
                          )
               ). \
    withColumn('yearcol_1s', 
               func.expr('transform(filter(yearcol_structs, x -> x.value = 1), f -> f.year)')
               ). \
    filter(func.size('yearcol_1s') >= 1). \
    withColumn('year_start', func.concat(func.lit('10/10/'), func.array_min('yearcol_1s'))). \
    withColumn('year_end', func.concat(func.lit('10/10/'), func.array_max('yearcol_1s'))). \
    show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step by step solution

Stack the dataframe to reshape into long format

```
# Primary id columns
keys = ['a', 'b', 'id']

# Create a dynamic stack expression 
stackexpr = f"stack({len(yearcols)}, %s) as (year, val)" \
            % ', '.join(f'"{c[-4:]}", {c}' for c in yearcols)

df = data_sdf.selectExpr(*keys, stackexpr)
df.show()

# +---+-----+---+----+---+
# |  a|    b| id|year|val|
# +---+-----+---+----+---+
# |  a|world|  1|2000|  0|
# |  a|world|  1|2001|  1|
# |  a|world|  1|2002|  1|
# |  a|world|  1|2003|  0|
# |  a|world|  1|2004|  0|
# |  a|world|  1|2005|  1|
# |  b|world|  2|2000|  0|
# |  b|world|  2|2001|  1|
# |  b|world|  2|2002|  1|
# |  b|world|  2|2003|  1|
# |  b|world|  2|2004|  1|
# |  b|world|  2|2005|  1|
# |  c|world|  3|2000|  1|
# |  c|world|  3|2001|  1|
# |  c|world|  3|2002|  0|
# |  c|world|  3|2003|  0|
# |  c|world|  3|2004|  1|
# |  c|world|  3|2005|  1|
# +---+-----+---+----+---+
```

Create a supplementary group key to identify blocks of rows having consecutive ones's. Then filter/remove the rows with zeros since we only consider one's to find start and end date

```
m = F.col('val') == 0
W = Window.partitionBy(*keys).orderBy('year')
df = df.withColumn('blocks', F.sum(m.cast('int')).over(W)).filter(~m)
df.show()

# +---+-----+---+----+---+------+
# |  a|    b| id|year|val|blocks|
# +---+-----+---+----+---+------+
# |  a|world|  1|2001|  1|     1|
# |  a|world|  1|2002|  1|     1|
# |  a|world|  1|2005|  1|     3|
# |  b|world|  2|2001|  1|     1|
# |  b|world|  2|2002|  1|     1|
# |  b|world|  2|2003|  1|     1|
# |  b|world|  2|2004|  1|     1|
# |  b|world|  2|2005|  1|     1|
# |  c|world|  3|2000|  1|     0|
# |  c|world|  3|2001|  1|     0|
# |  c|world|  3|2004|  1|     2|
# |  c|world|  3|2005|  1|     2|
# +---+-----+---+----+---+------+
```

Group the dataframe by `keys` along with `blocks` and aggregate `year` with `min` and `max`

```
df = (
    df
    .groupBy(*keys, 'blocks')
    .agg(F.min('year').alias('start'), F.max('year').alias('end'))
    .drop('blocks')
)

df.show()

# +---+-----+---+-----+----+
# |  a|    b| id|start| end|
# +---+-----+---+-----+----+
# |  a|world|  1| 2001|2002|
# |  a|world|  1| 2005|2005|
# |  b|world|  2| 2001|2005|
# |  c|world|  3| 2000|2001|
# |  c|world|  3| 2004|2005|
# +---+-----+---+-----+----+
```